# Cassandra nodes out of sync - NTP Out Of Sync Issue

Tags: ntp, cassandra-2.0

We have a cassandra cluster of 4 nodes, and it was working perfectly. After 2 of the nodes got restarted (since they were lxcs on the same machine), those 2 nodes are not able to join the cluster and fail with the error :

ERROR [MigrationStage:1] 2014-07-06 20:34:36,994 MigrationTask.java (line 55) Can't send migration
request: node /X.X.X.93 is down.

Two of the nodes (not restarted), are showing them DN in the nodetool status, while the others (ones which got restarted), are showing the others as UN.

I've checked the gossipinfo and that is fine.

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have cross_node_timeout = true and time between your servers is not in sync. You might want to check your ntp settings.

The new nodes might be dropping the requests for data that they are getting from the older nodes. Hence the ntp should be configured on all the nodes of cassandra.

Comment: Yes , NTP was not properly configured on the 2 new nodes . I think the old nodes were able to gossip but were dropping all the messages from new nodes as they were much ahead of the new nodes as compared to the timeout limits. Thank you for the quick reply.